# Laravel : How can load named route with dynamic arguments by javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, routes

I have a video player, I want after the end the video to run named route with arguments, I used this code. How can it work correctly?

```
function play_next() {
  var orderId = $('#orderId').val();
  var savedVidNum = $('#orderVideo').val();

  var url = document.getElementById('player').src;
  var filename = url.split('/').pop().split('#')[0].split('?')[0];
  filename = filename.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')
  if (filename < savedVidNum) {
    alert('just play next');
  } else {
    // load route here
    orderId = orderId.toString();
    savedVidNum = savedVidNum.toString();
    window.location.href = "{{URL::to('myroute/3/5')}}"-- -- - here I need to put orderId and savedVidNum
  }
}
```

Comment: Like this? `window.location.href = "{{URL::to('myroute/')}}" + orderId + "/" + savedVidNum`

Comment: I tried this but I get this : http://127.0.0.1:8000/myroute3/5 , instead of :http://127.0.0.1:8000/update_lession/3/5

Comment: it works after change it : indow.location.href = "{{URL::to('myroute/')}}" +'/' + orderId + "/" + savedVidNum

Answer (score 0):

I see there a form tag under another form tag that's why your post method not working. you need to all HTML form element under one form tag and also need to add the @csrf field.